# How to fetch data from database in Lumen using Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

I have user table and desc as follow.

user - user_id, email, password, token, date_created, status

I want to fetch this data in my controller.

SO, for this, I have model (User.php)

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model {
    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
}
```

in my route filte, this is written.

```
$app->post("api/register","APIController@register");
```

and now this is my controller (APIController.php)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Model\User;

class APIController extends BaseController
{
    public $http_status=200;

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function index(){
        echo 1;
    }

    public function register(Request $request){
        $json=array();
        $error=array();
        $error_status=0;

        if($request->has("email") && $request->has("password")){
            $email=trim($request->get("email"));
            $password=trim($request->get("password"));

            if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                array_push($error,"Email is not valid");
                $error_status=1;
            }

            if(strlen($password)<6){
                array_push($error, "Password length must be grater than 6");
                $error_status=1;
            }

            if(!$error_status){
                $user = User::all(); // here I have problem

                $json["status_code"]=1;
                $json["data"]=$user;
            }else{
                $json["status_code"]=0;
                $json["error"]=$error;
            }
        }else{
            $json["status_code"]=0;
            $json["status_remark"]="Some more data required";
        }

        return response()->json($json,$this->http_status);
    }

    public function login(){
        echo 1;
    }
}
```

when that commented part , when I try to fetch the data, then it is showing

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong

I am very new in lumen, I dont know how to do this. please help me.

see some other important file

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=lumen_api
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I have also uncommented this line in bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->withEloquent();
```

although it is not working. please help me.

Comment: Set `APP_DEBUG` to true and check if there are any errors in your `storage/logs/lumen.log` file.

Comment: In your `.env` file, of course. Forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: APP_DEBUG is already true. I am just checking in log file. @mrHooty

Comment: Uncomment this line `Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');` in the `bootstrap/app.php` to enable the Debug mode even if APP_DEBUG = true in lumen and tel us what is the error !!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are calling the wrong location for the model.

**Change**

```
use App\Model\User;
```

**To**

```
use App\User;
```

Then you should be able to call the model without any issues.

```
$users = User::all()->get();
```